# Should controller know about model relationships?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let's take a simple example with these 3 models: `Article`, `User`, `Tag`, with relationships:

`Article` -> has one `Author (User)`,
`Article` -> has many `Tags`.

When listing articles I also want to get the author and all the tags for each article.

I can do this 2 ways:

1. Build the `query` for finding the articles with the relationships in the controller.
   In laravel this would look like something like:

   `$articles = Article::with(array('author', 'tags'))->where('...')->get();`
2. Create a custom method in the `Article` model: `getArticles`, which return exactly the same thing:

   `return Article::with(array('author', 'tags'))->where('...')->get();`

In the second case all relations and query building is handled by the model.

So, my question is: should the controller know about model relationships, or that should be hidden from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to hide it. Consider a case where you need to do the same somewhere else. If it's in controller, you have to repeat youself. If it's in model, you just call (the same) model method again.